# Saving a column from a TXT file with tab delimited in a list

Tags: python, csv

I have a text file that has about 35 lines of "junk" information.  After that is tab-delimited data that I need to extract.  I need specific columns saved in a list.

First, I tried this way:

```
with open('BIOGRID-ORGANISM-Homo_sapiens-3.4.163.tab - Small.txt') as txtfile:

    readCSV = csv.reader(txtfile, delimiter='\t')
    objectids = []
    municodes = []
    results = []

    for row in readCSV[35]:
        objectid = row[3]
        municode = row[5]
        objectids.append(objectid)
        municodes.append(municode)
txtfile.close()
```

This gets the error

```
TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable.
```

Then, I tried something like this:

```
lol = list(csv.reader(open('BIOGRID-ORGANISM-Homo_sapiens-3.4.163.tab - Small.txt'), delimiter='\t'))

d = dict()
key = lol[0][0]      # cell A7
value = lol[0][0]
print(key)
print(value)
```

But this way, if I change the `[0][0]`, I will be out of range.

Comment: Please note that, since you failed to provide a full [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we *cannot* provide you with a working solution, nor can we help with subsequent error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried pandas with the skiprows option?

```
import pandas as pd
result = pd.read_csv('file.csv', skiprows=35)
relevant_column = list(result['relevant_column'])
```

Comment: I tried to replace the ['relevant_column'] by ['name of my column'] and [0] but both ways give me the error "KeyError: 'tALIASES_FOR_A'"

Comment: put the [0] outside of the list(.) With an example it would be easier...

Answer (score 0):

You've confused the reader (an iterator) with the results of the iteration.  WHat you're trying to do is better expressed if you first iterate over the reader, put all of the input into a list, and then slice the list:

```
data_rows = [_ for _ in readCSV][36:]
objectids = [_[3] for _ in data_rows]
municodes = [_[5] for _ in data_rows]
```

This is likely *not* the best way to get to your actual use case.  Since you're taking two columns -- and perhaps more -- from the spreadsheet in the file, I recommend that you use PANDAS (as `Pedro` already suggested) and stuff things directly into a data frame (df).  The df manipulation capabilities will save you from a *lot* of list comprehensions, filters, etc.